# Unable to Download file using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hi i want to download a file i wrote this code but while executing the file is not getting downloaded its coming up to the dialog box. please suggest

```
FirefoxProfile fprofile=new FirefoxProfile();
fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "D:\\Webdriver_download");
fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.folderlist", 2);
fprofile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv, application/pdf, application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/excel, application/vnd.ms- excel,application/x-excel,application/x-msexcel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml,application/excel,text/x-c");
fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(fprofile);
driver.get("http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/file/C35/P10/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("smilechart.xls")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing two things wrong here:

**Firstly:**

> browser.download.folderlist has folder**L**ist **(i.e. L is capital in list)**, keeping previous string will download it to downloads folder instead of your desired folder.

**Secondly:**

> browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk you have set **application/vnd.ms- excel**, it is **application/vnd.ms-excel** without space.

Hope this helps.